# Magnitude to Decibel always returns NaN in C#

Tags: c#, fft, unity-game-engine, nan, infinity

So my question has changed from returning Infinity to returning NaN.  If your FFT is always returning Infinity this may help (http://gerrybeauregard.wordpress.com/2011/04/01/an-fft-in-c/#comment-196).  So I think it is returning NaN because C# is trying to get the Square Root of a negative number HOWEVER, the number should not be negative based on the code below, because I am squaring both numbers before getting the square root (which should make them positive).  The number returned is negative, however.  I have tried it the inefficient of using multiple variables to get re * re and im * im and the two results added together, but the results are negative as well.  Math.Abs was no good either.  I have contacted the creator of the FFT Class (see my link above) and am waiting for his next reply.  I took some of the code below from an AS3 version of this I did before.  If I get the answer from the class creator before I get one here then I will post that.  Any insight is most helpful and thank you to everyone who has helped me so far in this.  I am an AS3 programmer coming to C# (because it's much more capable), so it's possible I missed something simple in my newbness.  I am using Unity.

```
 private const uint LOGN = 11; // Log2 FFT Length

    private const uint N = 1 << (int)LOGN; // FFT Length

    private const uint BUF_LEN = N; // Audio buffer length

    public FFT2 fft; // FFT Object

    private double[] tempIm = new double[N]; // Temporary Imaginary Number array

    private double[] m_mag = new double[N/2]; // Magnitude array

    private double[] m_win = new double[N]; // Hanning Window 

    private int fftCount = 0; // How many times the FFT has been performed

    private double SCALE = (double)20/System.Math.Log(10); // used to convert magnitude from FFT to usable dB

    private double MIN_VALUE = (double)System.Double.MinValue;
```

...

```
    // Hanning analysis window
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) // for i < 2048
        m_win[i] = (4.0/N) * 0.5*(1-Mathf.Cos(2*Mathf.PI*i/N)); // Hanning Vector [1] = 1 / 4595889085.750801
```

…

```
// Perform FFT
fft.run(tempRe, tempIm);

fftCount++;

// Convert from Decibel to Magnitude
for (int i = 0; i < N/2; i++) {

double re = tempRe[i]; // get the Real FFT Number at position i
double im = tempIm[i]; // get the Imaginary FFT Number at position i

m_mag[i] = Math.Sqrt(re * re + im * im); // Convert magnitude to decibels

m_mag[i] = SCALE * Math.Log(m_mag[i] + MIN_VALUE);

if (fftCount == 50 && i == 400) print ("dB @ 399: " + m_mag[399]);
}
```

The prior code prints:

```
dB @ 400: NaN

-5.56725062513722E+33
```

Thank you!!

Comment: take a look at [this sample](http://accord-net.origo.ethz.ch/wiki/sample_applications#Fourier)

Comment: Also check in debugger this line `m_mag[i] = 10 * Mathf.Log10(Mathf.Sqrt((float)((re * re) + (im * im))));` what are the values for real and imaginary?

Comment: Thank you! I'm looking at that framework now. There isn't any link to the actual Fourier source there, just a picture of the application. No luck in the Downloads section of the site for some reason, or on CodeProject where some of their other stuff is hosted.

After debugging, re and im both return usable numbers for both arrays in each index.  I keep checking this math but it's basically exactly what I used in the AS3 version of this, and the magnitude to decibel formula is what every source I check recommends.

Comment: What is the range of values in the tempRe array before the FFT?

Comment: @Jake the link indeed seems to be dead. Try downloading it from Softpedia. I now remembered that you first need to install [AForge.NET](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Components-Libraries/AForge-NET-Framework.shtml) which provides basic libraries and then [Accord.NET](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Components-Libraries/Accord-NET-Framework.shtml). Samples shall be provided with the second installation.

Comment: @ hotpaw2

The range is 2048.  N = 2048;

Comment: @oleksii

I'll see what I can find.

Comment: @hotpaw2

I just added all the variable values to the top of the post.  Do you think it has to do with the array lengths?  Like maybe I'm supposed to use N/2 somewhere?

Comment: I have solved the other issue, but there is a new one that relates to this.  Thanks for all your help.  I have updated the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `MIN_VALUE` to be `System.Double.MinValue`, which is the smallest possible double precision number. Adding anything other than `System.Double.MaxValue` or positive infinity will give a negative result. Taking the logarithm of a negative number returns `NaN`.

I'm guessing you want `MIN_VALUE` to be the smallest positive number. In C#, you use `System.Double.Epsilon` for that. (I know... it shouldn't be called that...)

Any other tiny value, like `1e-100`, will work as well.

Comment: Thanks! I think we found the answer at the same time :p I'm running into another problem now but I think it's with the FFT class itself.

Answer (score 0):

for (int i = 0; i < tempRe.Length; i++) tempRe[i] = m_win[i];

with the multiplication it will always be zero, unless that is what you wanted.

Comment: I just added the Hanning Window code to the top.  I need to multiply it in order to apply the Window.  If I set it to the Window then I'm not doing the FFT on the actual sample.  Debugging shows that tempRe contains usable data before the FFT.

Comment: I have solved the other issue, but there is a new one that relates to this. Thanks for all your help. I have updated the question above.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!  So it turns out that unlike C++, AS3, and some other languages, C# has negative minimum double value.

```
System.Double.MIN_VALUE = -1.7976931348623157E+308;
```

Getting the Square root of negatives causes the NaN error.  For more info see (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/numprogrammingcs.aspx).  I am having trouble getting an accurate dB reading now but I research and see what I can find.